# How to install old version of pnpm in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, wordpress, woocommerce, pnpm

I need to install the old version of `pnpm` v6.24.2 for `woocommerce-admin` current version is 7.9.0 also getting errors while running `npm build`:

```
Your pnpm version is incompatible with "/home/user/Desktop/woocommerce-admin".

Expected version: ^6.24.2
Got: 7.9.0

This is happening because the package's manifest has an engines.pnpm field specified.
To fix this issue, install the required pnpm version globally.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run:

```
pnpm install --global pnpm@latest-6
```

Alternatively, if you use [Corepack](https://nodejs.org/api/corepack.html), you may add this to your `package.json`:

```
{
  "packageManager": "pnpm@6.34.0"
}
```

Corepack automatically manages pnpm versions, so if you will run `pnpm` inside that project, Corepack will install and run the right version of pnpm.